# Classic ASP Type Mismatch

Tags: types, asp-classic

I'm having some troubles with a Session variable on Classic ASP. 
On line 19 of the following code, I'm getting a "Type mismatch: 'i'" error

- debug.asp is a module included in session.asp, another module in my program

> ```
> <%
> '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ' File:           /include/script/debug.asp
> ' Author:     Vladimir Charkot
> ' Create Date:    15/05/2013
> ' Description:    Generate a server debug log on client
> '----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> Redim debugTable(2,0)
>
> Sub initDebug(debugLevel)
>     Session("debugEntries") = 0
>     Session("debugLevel") = "e"
>     Call debugMsg("e","Debug initialized")
> End Sub
>
> Sub debugMsg(lv, str)
>     If IsEmpty(Session("debugEntries")) Then
>         i = 0
>     Else
>         i = Session("debugEntries")  <-- Line 21, Type mismatch error IF CInt() IS APPLIED TO SESSION VARIABLE
>     End If
>     i = i + 1                        <-- Line 23, Type mismatch error
>     Redim Preserve debugTable(2,i)
>     debugTable(0,i-1) = lv
>     debugTable(1,i-1) = str
>     Session("debugEntries") = CInt(i)
> End Sub
>
> Function debugToClient()
>     Dim list
>     Dim func
>     list = jsDebugList()
>     func = jsDebugFunction(list)
>     debugToClient = func
> End Function
>
> Function jsDebugList()
>     Dim i
>     Dim list
>     If IsEmpty(Session("debugEntries")) Then
>         i = 0
>     Else
>         i = Session("debugEntries")
>     End If
>     list = "["
>     for n = 0 to i - 2 
>     'Add the last one outside the loop
>         list = list & "{debugLevel : """ & debugTable(0,n) & """, message : """ & debugTable(1,n) & """}, "
>                ' i.e.: {debugLevel : "e", message : "Error on application"},
>     next
>     list = list & "{debugLevel : """ & debugTable(0,n) & """, message : """ & debugTable(1,n) & """}"
>     list = list & "]"
>     jsDebugList = list
> End Function
>
> Function jsDebugFunction(l)
>     Dim f
>     f =     "function debug(){"
>     f = f & "   debugList = " & l & ";"
>     f = f & "   for (elem in debugList){"
>     f = f & "       console.log(elem.debugLevel + "": "" + elem.message);"
>     f = f & "   }"
>     f = f & "}"
>     jsDebugFunction = f
> End Function
>
>
> %>
> ```

- Here is the session.asp relevant code, where debug subs and functions are called

> ```
> <!-- #include virtual="/gu/include/script/debug.asp" -->
>
> sub InitSession()
>     (...stuff...)
>     Call initDebug("e")
> end sub
>
> sub CheckSession()
>
>   ' If not a new session, this code has already been executed.
>   if stuff then
>       timeout()
>   end if
>
>   Call debugMsg("e", "CheckSession() Executed")
>
> end sub
> ```

- Lastly, session.asp is included on my page file, the one that I call open on my browser and returns the Type mismatch error.

Hope you can help me, I really think that I have already tried everything. Except Voodoo, black magic and that sort.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the value for Session("debugEntries") on line 17? Can you do a Response.Write and check the value before line 18 is called?

Comment: I'll try. It should be 0 the first time it's called, but I'll check. Great suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `debugMsg()` method before calling `initDebug()` method, which cause `Session("debugEntries")` to be empty, which turns out to be just an empty string.

When trying to convert a string to integer you'll indeed get Type Mismatch error, note that `i = i + 1` will try to convert automatically.

To solve this, either make sure to always call `initDebug()` first or add a "failsafe" code:

```
If Session("debugEntries")="" Then
    i = 0
Else  
    i = CInt(Session("debugEntries"))
End If
i = i + 1
```

Comment: And that, folks, is why you don't trust in automatically called methods. It did work! Thanks! :D

Comment: @Vladimir cheers, but what you mean by "automatically called"? ASP won't just call a method all by itself.

Comment: Ok, no, it didn't worked. After applying the failsafe the error jumped to the "for n = 0 to i - 2" line on Function jsDebugList() and I guessed it was just a matter of applying that change on every point it where necessary. However, after doing it I'm just getting again the same error on the same line, i.e. Type mismatch on line 21 now, which is:
    //If IsEmpty(Session("debugEntries")) Then
        //i = 0
    //Else
        //i = Session("debugEntries") <-- Line 21
    //End If
    //i = i + 1

If I try to use a CInt() on the Session variable I get a Type mismatch: 'CInt'

:(

Comment: Oh, and by "Automatically called" I meant that InitSession (the method that contains the InitDebug) was supposedly being called when it had to. The thing is that almost all code on this application isn't mine, so I must take for granted that certain things do work.

Comment: The comments don't support code formatting can you please edit your question with your new code (with failsafe) and point which line cause error?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought it would be understandable being just 6 lines, but you're right. Edited!

Comment: @Vladimir hmm... maybe I was wrong in assuming empty Session variables get the Empty value. Try to add such line somewhere: `Response.Write("Type is: " & TypeName(Session("debugEntries")) & "<br />")` what do you get as result? I would have checked it myself, but no classic is available for me right now.

Comment: @Vladimir lol classic ASP never stop amazing... and not in a good way.

Comment: Indeed. Working on a permission to migrate is my next goal in here.

Comment: Hey! It did worked! Now I double checked ;)
Thanks pal, it has been a pleasure working with this out you! :D

Comment: Cheers, don't forget to undo the undoing of the accept so the question won't stay open. :)

Answer (score 1):

Session "numbers" are actually strings. If you want an integer use:

```
i = CInt(Session("debugEntries"))
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to state that I have already tried that and if I go for it, the error is Type mismatch: 'CInt' on line 18 instead.